# How can Check the condition of the two spinner?

Tags: android, android-spinner

How can Check the condition of the two spinner?

I have two spinners in my project. 
I want to write unit conversion project 
How can the different conditions of the selected spinners item Understand ?

Similar to the image below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjURS.png

Comment: Show the code that you have so far and explain *exactly* where you are stuck.

Comment: you can get position of selected item and process second spinner depend on value :)

Comment: Can i use Overlapping switch statement ?
switch 1 cheked first spinner and inner switch cheked spinner 2

Comment: You can concat the value of two spinner together and then compare that concatenated value using switch.

Comment: can you elaborate more??

Answer (score 2):

```
firstSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
secondSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) parent;

    switch (spinner.getId()) {
    case R.id.first_spinner:
        // item selected on the first spinner
        // use position
        break;
    case R.id.second_spinner:
        // item selected on the second spinner
        // use position
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}
```